# Django utf-8 and django-mailer strangeness

Tags: python, django, encoding, utf-8, mailer

Latest django mailer from trunk http://github.com/jtauber/django-mailer/tree/master/docs/

Tested with Postgresql 8.4, sqlite3

## template

```
{{ title }}
```

## forms.py

```
#-*- coding: utf-8 -*-

if "mailer" in settings.INSTALLED_APPS:
    from mailer import send_mail
else:
    from django.core.mail import send_mail


...
        body_txt = render_to_string(
            'mails/share_deal/email_body.txt',
            {

                'title':u"éééààà",

            }
        )

        send_mail( "",  body_txt , "foo@ff.ff",  ["bar@kl.fd"],  fail_silently=True)
```

## Error

Environment:

Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://localhost:8000/deals/share/
Django Version: 1.2 SVN-13596
Python Version: 2.6.5
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.sites',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'django_extensions',
 'django.contrib.markup',
 'django.contrib.comments',
 'ajaxcomments',
 'mailer',
 'profiles',
 'tagging',
 'wmd',
 'core',
 'deals']
Installed Middleware:
('django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware')

```
Traceback:
File "/home/gregory/.virtualenvs/alpha/src/django/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  100.                     response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/home/gregory/projects/casadeal/casadeal/core/decorators.py" in wrap
  12.         return f(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/gregory/.virtualenvs/alpha/src/django/django/views/decorators/http.py" in inner
  37.             return func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/gregory/projects/casadeal/casadeal/deals/views.py" in share_deal
  22.             form.send_mail()
File "/home/gregory/projects/casadeal/casadeal/deals/forms.py" in send_mail
  89.             fail_silently=True)
File "/home/gregory/.virtualenvs/casadeal/src/django-mailer/mailer/__init__.py" in send_mail
  45.                  priority=priority).save()
File "/home/gregory/.virtualenvs/alpha/src/django/django/db/models/base.py" in save
  435.         self.save_base(using=using, force_insert=force_insert, force_update=force_update)
File "/home/gregory/.virtualenvs/alpha/src/django/django/db/models/base.py" in save_base
  528.                     result = manager._insert(values, return_id=update_pk, using=using)
File "/home/gregory/.virtualenvs/alpha/src/django/django/db/models/manager.py" in _insert
  195.         return insert_query(self.model, values, **kwargs)
File "/home/gregory/.virtualenvs/alpha/src/django/django/db/models/query.py" in insert_query
  1479.     return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(return_id)
File "/home/gregory/.virtualenvs/alpha/src/django/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py" in execute_sql
  783.         cursor = super(SQLInsertCompiler, self).execute_sql(None)
File "/home/gregory/.virtualenvs/alpha/src/django/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py" in execute_sql
  727.         cursor.execute(sql, params)
File "/home/gregory/.virtualenvs/alpha/src/django/django/db/backends/util.py" in execute
  15.             return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
File "/home/gregory/.virtualenvs/alpha/src/django/django/db/backends/postgresql_psycopg2/base.py" in execute
  44.             return self.cursor.execute(query, args)

Exception Type: DatabaseError at /deals/share/
Exception Value: ERREUR:  séquence d'octets invalide pour l'encodage « UTF8 » : 0xe9e9e9
HINT:  Cette erreur peut aussi survenir si la séquence d'octets ne correspond pas
au jeu de caractères attendu par le serveur, le jeu étant contrôlé par
« client_encoding ».

Basically it says that the encoding was not valid for UTF8 and contained   0xe9e9e9
```

This seems quite strange,

Any hints on where it could come from ?

Comment: Have you checked what characters are being submitted as the email address?

Comment: yes if i remove body everything is fine

Answer (score 0):

U+00E9 is LATIN SMALL LETTER E WITH ACUTE.

This MAY be the source (not necessarily the *cause*) of the problem: `'title':u"éééààà",`.

Cause may be something like `your_title.encode('latin1').decode('utf8')` (not in one step, of course).